# why does `brew search` need github credentials all of a sudden?

Tags: security, homebrew

This is **not** really expected or very reassuring from a package manager.

`brew search postgres`

gets me this credentials access request:

[image]

if I refuse, it does search and eventually provides the output:

```
2020-05-21 13:36:58.473 defaults[94976:1504467]
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleLanguages) does not exist
==> Formulae
check_postgres               postgresql@10                postgresql@9.4               postgresql@9.6
postgresql                   postgresql@11                postgresql@9.5               postgrest
==> Casks
navicat-for-postgresql                postgrespreferencepane                homebrew/cask-versions/postgres-beta
postgres                              sqlpro-for-postgres
```

Is this linked to `brew` somehow linking itself to github, as it seems to be saying in the version info?  How do I get rid of this behavior?  I suppose I can try updating brew, but it is already behaving in a risky-seeming fashion, so I thought I'd check here first.

```
(venv) jluc@sql$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.2.9
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 79b2f; last commit 2020-03-05)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision efcf9; last commit 2020-03-05)
```